# Kill specific powershell window

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to end a powershell window I spawned from a task running as SYSTEM. I don't have the ID of the process since I am launching it through psexec to be able to set the session id. The task and the target powershell process are in different sessions.

I thought it would be simple just to set a window title and then query on the window title but I am running to issues since processes running under the system don't seem to see the window title. For example when I run `get-process powershell | format-table -property Name, MainWindowTitle` as a user I get:

```
Name            MainWindowTitle
----            ---------------
powershell      Administrator: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
powershell      My Title 
powershell
```

By when I run the same command under the system account I get:

```
Name            MainWindowTitle
----            ---------------
powershell
powershell
powershell
```

I am not sure what is going on here. Is there a way to get the `MainWindowTitle` from the SYSTEM account? If not, is there something else I could query for that would return my powershell window and leave any other powershell processes running?

I am on Window 7 x64

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.5477
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

Comment: Can you have the process A find its own PID and output it to a file that the other process can read to know which PID to kill?

Answer (score 0):

If there is something unique about the command line of the process you'd like to kill, maybe you could use something like:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "Name='powershell.exe'" |
    Where-Object { $_.CommandLine -match $commandLineToMatch } |
    ForEach-Object { Stop-Process -WhatIf -Id $_.ProcessId }
```

I added -WhatIf for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the GetOwner() method on the Win32_Process object to get the user that started the process.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "Name='powershell.exe'" | ForEach-Object {

    if ($_.GetOwner().User -match 'system') {

        $_.Terminate()

    }
}
```